# How to assign variable from columns in an excel sheet in R studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to take averages of certain columns in my excel sheet that I have imported into R Studio but I am not sure how. For example,  I have the column "period type" and I want to take the average of the number of sales associated with "period type". But before I take the average of sales, how do I pull the column from my excel sheet if the excel sheet has already been imported?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information beyond descriptions.  See the following link for how to create an example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok, welcome to so, this is a really vague question, can you provide us the data using either the dput function or some other form of reproducible example see.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The following might be something you are looking for. Ensure header is set to TRUE, which names all the columns as you import it. The '$' allows you to reference one particular column from the data matrix.

```
diamond<- read.csv(file="diamonddata.csv",  header=TRUE) 
diamond$clarity
```